# yum update failed - How to resolve the depsolving problems

Tags: centos, rpm

I'm having CentOS 5.10 which i currently needed to install bc, i,e 
i issued `yum install bc`

At the end of command it is showing Error of

glibc-headers-2.5-118.el5_10.2.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
      --> Missing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 is needed by package glibc-headers-2.5-118.el5_10.2.i386 (installed)
    Error: Missing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 is needed by package glibc-headers-2.5-118.el5_10.2.i386 (installed)
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                            package-cleanup --dupes
                            rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Tried to clean repositories:

```
yum clean all
```

Then i issued `yum update`command

it is showing error as follows

```
[root@server1 Downloads]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.10 (Final)



[root@server1 Downloads]# yum update
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
 * extras: mirrors.liquidweb.com
 * ius: dfw.mirror.rackspace.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * updates: mirrors.liquidweb.com
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package GeoIP.i386 0:1.6.5-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: geoipupdate for package: GeoIP
--> Processing Dependency: GeoIP-GeoLite-data for package: GeoIP
---> Package GraphicsMagick.i386 0:1.3.24-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: liblzma.so.0 for package: GraphicsMagick
--> Processing Dependency: liblcms2.so.2 for package: GraphicsMagick
---> Package GraphicsMagick-doc.x86_64 0:1.3.24-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package automake.noarch 0:1.9.6-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: bind-libs = 30:9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.6 for package: bind-utils
---> Package bind-libs.i386 30:9.3.6-25.P1.el5_11.8 set to be updated
---> Package centos-release.x86_64 10:5-11.el5.centos set to be updated
---> Package centos-release-notes.x86_64 0:5.11-0 set to be updated
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.1.2-55.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: cpp
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) for package: cpp
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) for package: cpp
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6()(64bit) for package: cpp
---> Package cups-libs.i386 1:1.3.7-32.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package denyhosts.noarch 0:2.6-6.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: device-mapper = 1.02.67-2.el5 for package: device-mapper-event
---> Package device-mapper.i386 0:1.02.67-2.el5_11.1 set to be updated
---> Package dmidecode.x86_64 1:2.12-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package e2fsprogs.x86_64 0:1.39-37.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libblkid.so.1()(64bit) for package: e2fsprogs
--> Processing Dependency: libe2p.so.2()(64bit) for package: e2fsprogs
--> Processing Dependency: libcom_err.so.2()(64bit) for package: e2fsprogs
--> Processing Dependency: libss.so.2()(64bit) for package: e2fsprogs
--> Processing Dependency: libext2fs.so.2()(64bit) for package: e2fsprogs
--> Processing Dependency: libuuid.so.1()(64bit) for package: e2fsprogs
---> Package e2fsprogs-libs.i386 0:1.39-37.el5 set to be updated
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.1.2-55.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) for package: gcc
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.1.2-55.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) for package: gcc-c++
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 for package: glibc-headers
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.5-123.el5_11.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.5-123.el5_11.3 for package: glibc
---> Package glibc-devel.i386 0:2.5-123.el5_11.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.5-123.el5_11.3 for package: glibc-devel
---> Package hwdata.noarch 0:0.213.30-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package initscripts.x86_64 0:8.45.45-1.el5.centos set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libglib-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: initscripts
---> Package ius-release.noarch 0:1.0-14.ius.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: jasper-libs = 1.900.1-14.el5 for package: jasper
---> Package jasper-libs.i386 0:1.900.1-15.el5 set to be updated
---> Package krb5-libs.i386 0:1.6.1-80.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package libXfont.i386 0:1.2.2-1.0.6.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package libgcc.i386 0:4.1.2-55.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libgcj.i386 0:4.1.2-55.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libstdc++.i386 0:4.1.2-55.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libstdc++-devel.i386 0:4.1.2-55.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libvolume_id.i386 0:095-14.33.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package libxml2.i386 0:2.6.26-2.1.25.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package libxml2-devel.i386 0:2.6.26-2.1.25.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package lvm2.x86_64 0:2.02.88-13.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.5()(64bit) for package: lvm2
--> Processing Dependency: libncurses.so.5()(64bit) for package: lvm2
---> Package mkinitrd.i386 0:5.1.19.6-82.el5 set to be updated
---> Package nash.x86_64 0:5.1.19.6-82.el5 set to be updated
---> Package nspr.i386 0:4.11.0-1.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package nss.i386 0:3.21.0-6.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package openldap.i386 0:2.3.43-29.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package openssl.i686 0:0.9.8e-40.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package pam.i386 0:0.99.6.2-14.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package perl.i386 4:5.8.8-43.el5_11 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: popt = 1.10.2.3-34.el5 for package: rpm-python
--> Processing Dependency: popt = 1.10.2.3-34.el5 for package: rpm
---> Package popt.i386 0:1.10.2.3-36.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.3.3-7.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.3.so()(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: libldap-2.3.so.0()(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: liblber-2.3.so.0()(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.2()(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: postfix
--> Processing Dependency: rpm-libs = 4.4.2.3-34.el5 for package: rpm-python
--> Processing Dependency: rpm-libs = 4.4.2.3-34.el5 for package: rpm
---> Package rpm-libs.i386 0:4.4.2.3-36.el5_11 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: rpm = 4.4.2.3-36.el5_11 for package: rpm-libs
---> Package shadow-utils.x86_64 2:4.0.17-23.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libacl.so.1(ACL_1.1)(64bit) for package: shadow-utils
--> Processing Dependency: libacl.so.1()(64bit) for package: shadow-utils
--> Processing Dependency: libselinux.so.1()(64bit) for package: shadow-utils
--> Processing Dependency: libaudit.so.0()(64bit) for package: shadow-utils
---> Package sysstat.x86_64 0:7.0.2-13.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package GeoIP-GeoLite-data.noarch 0:2016.07-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: GeoIP-GeoLite-data-extra = 2016.07-1.el5 for package: GeoIP-GeoLite-data
---> Package audit-libs.x86_64 0:1.8-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 30:9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libgssapi_krb5.so.2(gssapi_krb5_2_MIT)(64bit) for package: bind-libs
--> Processing Dependency: libgssapi_krb5.so.2()(64bit) for package: bind-libs
---> Package cyrus-sasl-lib.x86_64 0:2.1.22-7.el5_8.1 set to be updated
---> Package db4.x86_64 0:4.3.29-10.el5_5.2 set to be updated
---> Package device-mapper.x86_64 0:1.02.67-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libsepol.so.1()(64bit) for package: device-mapper
---> Package dropbox.x86_64 0:0.7.110-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libXext.so.6()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libXrandr.so.2()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libXcursor.so.1()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libXrender.so.1()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libSM.so.6()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libXcomposite.so.1()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libXinerama.so.1()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libXdamage.so.1()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libXfixes.so.3()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libpango-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libXi.so.6()(64bit) for package: dropbox
--> Processing Dependency: libfontconfig.so.1()(64bit) for package: dropbox
---> Package e2fsprogs-libs.x86_64 0:1.39-37.el5 set to be updated
---> Package geoipupdate.x86_64 0:2.2.1-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: geoipupdate
---> Package glib2.x86_64 0:2.12.3-4.el5_3.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 for package: glibc-headers
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.5-123.el5_11.3 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.5-123.el5_11.3 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.5-123.el5_11.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: jasper-libs = 1.900.1-14.el5 for package: jasper
---> Package lcms2.i386 0:2.8-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libacl.x86_64 0:2.2.39-8.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libattr.so.1(ATTR_1.0)(64bit) for package: libacl
--> Processing Dependency: libattr.so.1()(64bit) for package: libacl
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.1.2-55.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libselinux.x86_64 0:1.33.4-5.7.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libstdc++.x86_64 0:4.1.2-55.el5 set to be updated
---> Package mysqlclient15.x86_64 0:5.0.92-3.ius.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libpcap for package: mysqlclient15
---> Package openldap.x86_64 0:2.3.43-29.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package openssl.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-40.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package pcre.x86_64 0:6.6-9.el5 set to be updated
---> Package popt.x86_64 0:1.10.2.3-34.el5 set to be updated
---> Package readline.x86_64 0:5.1-3.el5 set to be updated
---> Package rpm.x86_64 0:4.4.2.3-36.el5_11 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libplds4.so()(64bit) for package: rpm
--> Processing Dependency: libnssutil3.so()(64bit) for package: rpm
--> Processing Dependency: libbz2.so.1()(64bit) for package: rpm
--> Processing Dependency: libplc4.so()(64bit) for package: rpm
--> Processing Dependency: libelf.so.1()(64bit) for package: rpm
--> Processing Dependency: libnspr4.so()(64bit) for package: rpm
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so()(64bit) for package: rpm
---> Package rpm-libs.x86_64 0:4.4.2.3-34.el5 set to be updated
---> Package xz-libs.i386 0:4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package GeoIP-GeoLite-data-extra.noarch 0:2016.07-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package atk.x86_64 0:1.12.2-1.fc6 set to be updated
---> Package bzip2-libs.x86_64 0:1.0.3-6.el5_5 set to be updated
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.15.5-17.el5_9 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libidn.so.11()(64bit) for package: curl
---> Package elfutils-libelf.x86_64 0:0.137-3.el5 set to be updated
---> Package fontconfig.x86_64 0:2.4.1-7.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libfreetype.so.6()(64bit) for package: fontconfig
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0()(64bit) for package: fontconfig
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 for package: glibc-headers
---> Package gtk2.x86_64 0:2.10.4-30.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libtiff.so.3()(64bit) for package: gtk2
--> Processing Dependency: libcairo.so.2()(64bit) for package: gtk2
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62()(64bit) for package: gtk2
--> Processing Dependency: libcups.so.2()(64bit) for package: gtk2
--> Processing Dependency: jasper-libs = 1.900.1-14.el5 for package: jasper
---> Package krb5-libs.x86_64 0:1.6.1-80.el5_11 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libkeyutils.so.1(KEYUTILS_0.3)(64bit) for package: krb5-libs
--> Processing Dependency: libkeyutils.so.1()(64bit) for package: krb5-libs
---> Package libSM.x86_64 0:1.0.1-3.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libICE.so.6()(64bit) for package: libSM
---> Package libX11.x86_64 0:1.0.3-11.el5_7.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXdmcp.so.6()(64bit) for package: libX11
--> Processing Dependency: libXau.so.6()(64bit) for package: libX11
---> Package libXcomposite.x86_64 0:0.3-5.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXcursor.x86_64 0:1.1.7-1.2 set to be updated
---> Package libXdamage.x86_64 0:1.0.3-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXext.x86_64 0:1.0.1-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXfixes.x86_64 0:4.0.1-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXi.x86_64 0:1.0.1-4.el5_4 set to be updated
---> Package libXinerama.x86_64 0:1.0.1-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXrandr.x86_64 0:1.1.1-3.3 set to be updated
---> Package libXrender.x86_64 0:0.9.1-3.1 set to be updated
---> Package libattr.x86_64 0:2.4.32-1.1 set to be updated
---> Package libpcap.x86_64 14:0.9.4-15.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libsepol.x86_64 0:1.15.2-3.el5 set to be updated
---> Package nspr.x86_64 0:4.11.0-1.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package nss.x86_64 0:3.21.0-6.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package pango.x86_64 0:1.14.9-8.el5.centos.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXft.so.2()(64bit) for package: pango
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cairo.x86_64 0:1.2.4-5.el5 set to be updated
---> Package cups-libs.x86_64 1:1.3.7-32.el5_11 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.13(GNUTLS_1_3)(64bit) for package: cups-libs
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.13()(64bit) for package: cups-libs
---> Package expat.x86_64 0:1.95.8-11.el5_8 set to be updated
---> Package freetype.x86_64 0:2.2.1-32.el5_9.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 for package: glibc-headers
--> Processing Dependency: jasper-libs = 1.900.1-14.el5 for package: jasper
---> Package keyutils-libs.x86_64 0:1.2-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libICE.x86_64 0:1.0.1-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXau.x86_64 0:1.0.1-3.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXdmcp.x86_64 0:1.0.1-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXft.x86_64 0:2.1.10-1.1 set to be updated
---> Package libidn.x86_64 0:0.6.5-1.1 set to be updated
---> Package libjpeg.x86_64 0:6b-38 set to be updated
---> Package libtiff.x86_64 0:3.8.2-19.el5_10 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 for package: glibc-headers
---> Package gnutls.x86_64 0:1.4.1-16.el5_10 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libgcrypt.so.11(GCRYPT_1.2)(64bit) for package: gnutls
--> Processing Dependency: libgcrypt.so.11()(64bit) for package: gnutls
--> Processing Dependency: libgpg-error.so.0()(64bit) for package: gnutls
--> Processing Dependency: jasper-libs = 1.900.1-14.el5 for package: jasper
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 for package: glibc-headers
--> Processing Dependency: jasper-libs = 1.900.1-14.el5 for package: jasper
---> Package libgcrypt.x86_64 0:1.4.4-7.el5_10 set to be updated
---> Package libgpg-error.x86_64 0:1.4-2 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
jasper-1.900.1-14.el5.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: jasper-libs = 1.900.1-14.el5 is needed by package jasper-1.900.1-14.el5.i386 (installed)
glibc-headers-2.5-118.el5_10.2.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 is needed by package glibc-headers-2.5-118.el5_10.2.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 is needed by package glibc-headers-2.5-118.el5_10.2.i386 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: jasper-libs = 1.900.1-14.el5 is needed by package jasper-1.900.1-14.el5.i386 (installed)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: I normally use `yum upgrade yum rpm` before a large update such as yours, to make sure that any rpm / yum logic fixes are inplace first.

Comment: Run `yum distro-sync` first, and _if it fails_ post its output. If it succeeds, it probably will have fixed the problem.

Comment: "yum distro-sync" this command is not recognized in the Terminal, Error Showing how to use yum : yum [options] COMMAND

Comment: Fedora yum (dnf) has distro-sync.  For RHEL and Centos, it is probably yum distribution-synchronization.  I liked rug way back when that accepted short versions of commands as long as they were unique.